# Save product custom meta as order item meta when manually adding products to WooCommerce admin orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I'm trying to add custom product meta to order item meta when adding products to the order from the admin. This is my code, which does nothing in the backend ...

```
// Order items: Save product "location" as order item meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta', 'action_before_save_order_item_callback' );
function action_before_save_order_item_callback($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    if ( $location = $values['data']->get_meta('location') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( 'location', $location ); // Save as order item meta
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the right function hook arguments which are `$item_id`, `$item`, `$order` and not using the right way. Try the following instead *(code is commented)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta', 'action_before_save_order_item_callback', 9999, 3 );
function action_before_save_order_item_callback( $item_id, $item, $order ) {
    $product  = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product Object
    $location = $product->get_meta('location'); // Get custom meta data

    // If custom field is empty on a product variation check on the parent variable product
    if( empty($location) && $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ) {
        $parent_product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() ); // Get parent WC_Product Object
        $location = $product->get_meta('location'); // Get custom meta data
    }

    // If product meta data exist
    if( ! empty($location) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( 'location', $location ); // Set it as order item meta
        $item->save(); // save it
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.